# What are some good introductory books on complex analysis?

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for self study books or general interest (above the layman level) books on complex analysis.

Comment: I don't know if you would consider that an introductory book, I am self-studying Rudin's real complex analysis and I am liking it a lot http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-International-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0070542341

Comment: My professor was unhappy with anything but Basic Complex Analysis by Marsden and Hoffman so it was the course literature. It made the course much harder since the book seems to be out of print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few of my favourites:

- Stewart and Tall [Complex Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Complex-Analysis-Ian-Stewart/dp/0521245133) - does not demand massive pre-requisites.
- Needham [Visual Complex Analysis](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469) - fantastic for getting a visual feel for what is going on with complex functions and the complex plane.
- Palka [An Introduction to Complex Function Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797427X) - a very thorough treatment for a first course.
- Flanigan [Complex Variables](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486613887) - very nice introduction via harmonic functions, and has the advantage of being a cheap Dover edition.

I am also a great fan of some of the older treatments by Ahlfors, Nevanlinna and Paatero, as well as Rudin, but could not honestly recommend any of these for an introductory course.

Answer (score 4):

I really loved Ahlfors' Complex Analysis (which is probably the most famous, and most absurdly expensive book on the subject). This is complex analysis from an analytic point of view. If you are interested in complex analysis from the point of view of geometry Freitag and Busam  Complex Analysis is an interesting well written option you can consider.(http://books.google.com/books/about/Complex_Analysis.html?id=M-fI9tPrBRIC)

Moreover another book I particularly liked is Function of One Complex variable by Conway (http://books.google.com/books/about/Functions_of_One_Complex_Variable_I.html?id=9LtfZr1snG0C). It covers a lot of subjects, from basic complex analysis to interesting topics such as normal families...

Answer (score 0):

This book is free and very well written. Complex Analysis by George Cain. 
http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/complex.html